What is this structure? Can I remove it?
This structure is in my garage.  It’s a piece of wood that goes to the roof and is attached to a bolted on piece of wood that’s mid wall.  On the other end of the garage theres a piece of bolted on wood mid wall but nothing going into the roof.  The box like enclosure on the ceiling is empty.  Trying to figure out what this is and if I can remove it.

Bolted on usually means structural, so removing it should be done after a building expert(engineer, licensed builder, inspector) sees it.

Is the thing on top the plenum?  Is it hollow and metallic?

I mean, the top looks like a duct or a chase of some kind.  The bottom looks like a board spaced out from the wall, maybe to support the cabinets?  Vertical member is unclear—got better pics?
